# How do I record SQL transactions with SQL Server Express

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, profiler, express-edition

With a test migration from 2000 to 2008R2 Express, one function from the client application fails silently. I'd like to find out what SQL is running and why it fails.

I think I would have attacked this with the profiler in 2000 (not sure)? However this tool is absent from the Express Edition.

Is it possible to do what I want without any tool, eg just with T-SQL, and how would I go about it?

Comment: Is the function wrapped in other code?

Comment: Yes - we don't even have the source (sorry by 'function' I meant a 'function' of the application not a db function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need a profiler of some variety if the call is wrapped up.

One of:

- Download a trial version, install client tools only
- 3rd party http://sites.google.com/site/sqlprofiler/

Comment: I can't work out - is it a trial version or is it open source?

Comment: My mistake: I didn't say "one of". I can't comment on the 3rd party tool.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that in SQL Server Express, just because you don't have the SQL Server Profiler application you are still able to use the Trace objects.

Please reference this to show an explanation of all the stored procs and functions that you can and need to use: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191006.aspx

Comment: Thanks. I assume these "trace objects" are what SQL Profiler and the 3rd party equivalent uses?